# How to apply reloaded array to a dropdown menu?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have

```
{
 xtype: 'combo',
 id: 'multiplier',
 triggerAction: "all",
 store: multWaqrranty,
 fieldLabel: 'Multiply'
}
```

And `var multWaqrranty = [1, 1.5];`

What function should I use in order to reload a new data? Like `var multPaid = [0.25, 0.4, 1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load ArrayStore explicity, for example,

```
var multWaqrranty = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
   // store configs
   autoDestroy: true,
   // reader configs
   fields: [
      {name: 'value', type: 'float'}
   ]
});

{
 xtype: 'combo',
 id: 'multiplier',
 triggerAction: 'all',
 store: multWaqrranty,
 mode: 'local',
 fieldLabel: 'Multiply',
 valueField: 'value',
 displayField: 'value'
}

// load data
multWaqrranty.loadData([[1,1], [1.5,1.5]],false);

// load new data
multWaqrranty.loadData([[0.25,0.25], [0.4,0.4], [1,1]],false);
```

Comment: I had to use [[0.25], [0.4], [1]]